# How can I discover what JSON endpoints a WCF service has?

Tags: json, wcf

How can I discover what JSON endpoints a WCF service has?

I know I can append wsdl to the URL and get the SOAP call details ...

```
http://myserver/Explore/TestService.svc?wsdl
```

but how can I get what JSON calls the service has?

Comment: you want JSON endpoint or you want to know about exposed json service methods..?

Comment: If you want to know about just exposed method names by json endpoint, just use help like this : "http://myserver/Explore/TestService.svc/help".

Comment: Shame, the service I'm looking at doesn't have such a /help

Comment: It might not be enabled by service provider, check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230442(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - there is no built-in mechanism for rest endpoint metadata - you just need to know which http options are applicable to which resources. You'll also need to have some types ready to deserialise to - if you can't get this information off the service provider then you'll need to infer them from the response json.

There is a service discovery standard called [WADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language) which is supposed to do for http what wsdl does for SOAP. However unless the service provider has published one you're out of luck.

Comment: You know I had a bad feeling you were going to say that  :-(